# SQL 2008 R2 says access denied when logging in remotely

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, authentication, sql-server-2008-r2

I have an SQL 2008 R2 server and a monitoring server both on the same physical network (but different VLANs). The monitoring server is always connecting to the SQL server to run a query and check the output. However, the monitoring server is intermittently failing to connect to the SQL server multiple times a day. I tested while the issue is occurring by trying to connect from SQL Management Studio on the monitoring server and I get this error:

[image]

When I check the event viewer on the SQL server, I see the following two errors grouped together multiple times, for each corresponding failed login attempt:

[image]

[image]

However I have checked the SQL server and confirmed that mixed mode authentication is ON, there is no limit to concurrent connections, remote connections are allowed, and anyways MOST of the time the monitoring server is able to connect to SQL. If it was a network issue, I'd assume the error wouldn't be recorded in the event viewer on the SQL server. But I'm not sure what else it could be at this point.

Any help or tips would be greatly appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Sometimes odd auth problems can be due to the clock. Are all the clocks synced on your servers?

Comment: Yes, the clocks are the same on both servers